# how to convert JavaScript/jQuery script into a loop

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm very new to JavaScript and jQuery (sorry in advance).  I'm trying to convert the following script below to a loop.  Any suggestions would be great.  I would like to set the first variable "flag1" to loop 1-5 and in the array (arr1) loop the middle number 1-5 rather than writing 5 sets.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
{
  var flag1 = ^f('flaghigh_1').get()^;
  var arr1=['#QE1_1_1','#QE1_1_2','#QE1_1_7','#QE1_1_99'];

  for(var i=0;i<arr1.length;i++)
  {
        if(flag1 == '1') 
        { $(arr1[i]).parent().addClass("confirmit-cellerror"); }
        else
        { $(arr1[i]).parent().removeClass("confirmit-cellerror"); }
}}
</script>


<script type="text/javascript">
{
  var flag2 = ^f('flaghigh_2').get()^;
  var arr1=['#QE1_2_1','#QE1_2_2','#QE1_2_7','#QE1_2_99'];

  for(var i=0;i<arr1.length;i++)
  {
        if(flag2 == '1') 
        { $(arr1[i]).parent().addClass("confirmit-cellerror"); }
        else
        { $(arr1[i]).parent().removeClass("confirmit-cellerror"); }
}}
</script>
<script type="text/javascript">
{
  var flag3 = ^f('flaghigh_3').get()^;
  var arr1=['#QE1_3_1','#QE1_3_2','#QE1_3_7','#QE1_3_99'];

  for(var i=0;i<arr1.length;i++)
  {
        if(flag3 == '1') 
        { $(arr1[i]).parent().addClass("confirmit-cellerror"); }
        else
        { $(arr1[i]).parent().removeClass("confirmit-cellerror"); }
}}
</script>
<script type="text/javascript">
{
  var flag4 = ^f('flaghigh_4').get()^;
  var arr1=['#QE1_4_1','#QE1_4_2','#QE1_4_7','#QE1_4_99'];

  for(var i=0;i<arr1.length;i++)
  {
        if(flag4 == '1') 
        { $(arr1[i]).parent().addClass("confirmit-cellerror"); }
        else
        { $(arr1[i]).parent().removeClass("confirmit-cellerror"); }
}}
</script>
```

Comment: You shouldn't go asking people to do stuff for you. You should simply try to do it yourself and then come back if you get stuck in a specific situation that you can't get out of.

Answer (score 0):

You mean this?:

```
 for(const n of [1, 2, 3, 4]) {
   const flag = f(`flaghigh_${n}`).get();
   const arr = [`#QE1_${n}_1`, `#QE1_${n}_2`, `#QE1_${n}_7`, `#QE1_¢{n}_99`];

   for(const el of arr) {
     if(flag === '1') { 
        $(el).parent().addClass("confirmit-cellerror"); 
     } else { 
        $(el).parent().removeClass("confirmit-cellerror"); 
     }
   }
 }
```

This uses a simple `for..of` loop and template literals.

Comment: The script above is definitely better than mine, thank you!  I've been trying to make some minor changes (changed cent to dollar sign, tried to directly reference the flag variable) since it is not currently working for me...but thank you for trying to help.